# All html canvas shapes are given the color of the last object added

Tags: html, canvas

I was trying to do an Olympic type flag, purely as a way of learning how to draw in JavaScript. This should draw two circles - one blue, one black...
Here is the code (which I apologise for, been moving things between the two functions - Not sure how to refer to the context non-explicitly):

```
function drawCircle(ctx,x,y,radius, color){
  var startAngle = 0;
  var endAngle = (Math.PI*2);
  var clockwise = true;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.arc(x,y,radius,startAngle,endAngle, clockwise);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath;
}
function drawCircles(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvasArea');  
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
     if (canvas.getContext){    
        drawCircle(ctx,50,25,25, 'blue');
        drawCircle(ctx,100,25,25, 'black');
    }
}
```

I get two black circles. I presume I'm not differentiating between the two shapes, therefore the properties of the 2nd are applied to the 1st.

How do I make that distinction? I was thinking of making clicking each one raise an action. Am I going about this incorrectly from the start?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you are never calling `beginPath()`!

```
function drawCircle(ctx,x,y,radius, color){
  var startAngle = 0;
  var endAngle = (Math.PI*2);
  var clockwise = true;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath(); // <-- Need me!!
  ctx.arc(x,y,radius,startAngle,endAngle, clockwise);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath;
}
```

Since you don't call beginPath, you are drawing one blue circle, then you are *continuing* a path that now has two circles (the old one and the new one), and drawing that path (and thus both circles) black!

Instead you want to draw one blue circle, fill it blue, *begin a new path*, and draw that one black.

Live code:

http://jsfiddle.net/5PDUb/1/

Comment: @Jonas  I don't have enough rep to vote up things & wasn't aware I could vote up in my own thread. For some reason the outline of a tick meant nothing to me! Thank you.

Comment: @gaijintendo: Sorry, I have upvoted your question, so you get more reputation.